# expected string or bytes-like object when import re

Tags: python, if-statement, python-re

i have code

```
expected_letters = [6,7,8]
if len(license_plate)= expected_letters:  
   return True

if re.match("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]", license_plate):
    return True
    
if re.match("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]", license_plate):
    return True

if re.match("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]", license_plate):
    return True

else:
    return False
```

code `if len(licence_plate)` is it true?

when i run `if re.match` there is error: re.py - return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

how to fix this?

Comment: How is `license_plate` defined? As the exception says, it can only be a string or a bytes-like object. If it's something else, like a list... well, there's your problem.

Comment: (Really, though, this is the case where the exception itself tells you _exactly_ what your problem is, so it's hard to see what's left to ask a question about. If you're unclear on what kind of object `license_plate` contains, try logging `type(license_plate)` and `repr(license_plate)`).

Comment: `if len(license_plate)= expected_letters:` is wrong in several ways. `=` is for assignment, the comparison operator is `==`. `len(license_plate)` is a number, `expected_letters` is a list, so they can never be equal; I think you meant `if len(license_plate) in (6, 7, 8):`

Comment: Why are you using 3 different regular expressions? Why not a single regexp ending with `[A-Z]{1,3}`? Also, make sure you anchor the regep with `$`, otherwise it will match when there are more characters after the pattern.